# Usage of "this" before a long phrase

Tags: determiners

Someone wrote:

> Finally **this university semester** finished. **Every university semester** with different students and classes, always bring me **many new** experiences.

I feel while "this semester" sounds fluent, "this university semester" or "Every university semester" doesn't sound fluent! I don't know why! Maybe it is too long and complete to be used after "this". Anyway, I want to know is there any nuances about using "this" that can be applied here?

In the last phrase I prefer "new experiences" than "many new experiences". I feel "many" is extra, but again don't know why!

Answer (score 2):

You can say like this :

> Finally the semester **at the university is finished** ( *or*, **has ended** ). Every **such** semester with different students and classes, always bring**s** me **a couple of** new experiences.

Using ***university semester*** in every sentences makes the sentence sound monotonous.

Yes, "many" can be used for a large number of experiences, but if you don't think you gather that much experiences, you can use ***a couple of*** instead of ***many***.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know is there any nuances about using "this" that can be
>   applied here

Considering your sentence, I would say you might want to use *this* only because the semester denotes a particular semester, that is different from the previous ones. So, if you don't want to add any specific detail about it, I would say you can remove it:

> Finally the semester **is finished** (or **has ended**). Every semester with
>   different students and classes, always bring**s** me **new** experiences.